# Billionaire making space elevator

Tags: story-identification

The story basically has a billionaire wanting to build a space elevator. He begins digging a massive hole on earth and another group building the cable on an asteroid. He then propels the asteroid towards earth landing the cable in the hole and exploding  charges to bury the end of the cable.

Comment: http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/space_elevator

Comment: Was this a novel or a short story?

Comment: Im sorry its a novel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the story you're remembering is in the novel *The Web Between Worlds* by Charles Sheffield.  Amazon summary:

> Rob Merlin, a famous and sought-after engineer, is recruited by Darius Regulo, the aged, wealthy, and eccentric "king of space" to construct a bridge between earth and space.

Construction concludes with the end of the space tether plunging into a deep hole near Quito, Ecuador and explosives being detonated to cause landslides to refill the hole.

Comment: My gosh! Ive been trying for so long to remember this book! Thank you so much. I cant believe I hadnt found this place sooner. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I am still new to this site. How do I mark the answer to my question as accepted?

Comment: Clck on the green check mark.

Comment: Sorry got it. The checkmark looked like a down arrow. Im learning

Comment: Ive ordered this book so I can enjoy it once again. This book is why Ive worked for Elon Musk at SpaceX and also why I currently work for Blue Origin.